# Question about timeout_ns parameter in rclc_executor_spin_some

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-humble, embedded-systems, micro-ros

**I have a question about the timeout_ns parameter of the rclc_executor_spin_some function.**

As far as I know, the timeout_ns parameter of rclc_executor_spin_some is interpreted in two ways.

Can you tell me which of the two methods is correct?

**First**, the executor seems to run periodically when it times out.

**The second** is considered to be the time it takes to complete only the timeout period when executing the function.

---

And to understand the operation of the rclc_executor_spin_some function, we looked inside the rclc_executor_spin_some function in rclc/executor.c.

I have two questions.
**The first question** is:
It seems that the timeout_ns parameter is used in the rcl_wait function inside rclc_executor_spin_some. At this time, does the function terminate after waiting for timeout_ns?

**The second question** is as follows.
I understood that when rclc_executor_spin_some is executed, the waiting subscription callback function and Timer callback function are executed.
Is it correct that all waiting subscription callback functions and Timer callback functions are processed and terminated before rclc_executor_spin_some terminates?
Or is there a limited number?

thank you

Comment: [One question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/280335)